# Многомерные массивы c# с разными типами

Tags: php, c#

В php можно создать многомерный массив и добавить в него ключ со значением без указания типа, а как такое сделать в c#?

```
$array['key1'] = true;
$array['key2'] = false;
$array['key3'][0] = [1, 2, 3];
```

Comment: В C# это не требуется, т.к. есть нормальные классы

Comment: @Андрей где можно посмотреть пример?

Comment: Пример чего? Вам не нужен ассоциативный массив. Создайте класс: `public class MyObj { public bool Key1 { get; set; } public bool Key2 { get; set; } public List<int> Key3 { get; } }`

Comment: @Андрей это не решает проблему, т.к. вместо key1 может быть любое значение.

Comment: Приведите пример, где это может потребоваться, я напишу вам как это сделать в C#

Comment: HashTable и ручное приведение типов. Или Dictionary<string, object> и опять же приведение типов при чтении

Comment: @vitidev, часто ли вы это практикуете при программировании на C#. Я конечно понимаю, что `писать на фортране можно на любом языке`, но  зачем это делать?

Comment: @Андрей, вот [пример](https://pastebin.com/dEwGEAM6)

Comment: @Андрей когда шарп пересекается с php на уровне совместимых данных, то приходится. А так object довольно редко у меня.

Comment: @vitidev, ну на стыках динамического языка с C# понятно

Comment: @frago, вам подойдет обычный _типизированный_ словарь - `Dictionary<string, bool> d` и проверка типа `if (!d.ContainsKey(name)) return false; return d[name];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**дополнительная информация :** O примерах есть проблема приведение к другим типом 'Boxing-Unboxing'.

Используйте 'Jagged Arrays'.

```
object[][] obj = new object[3][];
obj [0] = new bool[] { true,false };
obj [1] = new string[] { "test","test2","test3"};
obj [2] = new int[] { 1,2,3 };
```

или можно использовать 'Generic Collections'.

```
Dictionary<string,object[]> obj = new Dictionary<string,object[]>();
obj.Add("key1",new object[] { 1,true,"test1"});
obj["key1"][0] = 15;
```

Answer (score 4):

Хотя это и возможно, так делать не надо:

https://ideone.com/1m4fwV

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    var a = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

    a["key1"] = true;
    a["key2"] = false;
    a["key3"] = new List<dynamic> { new dynamic [] {1, 2, 3} };

    Console.WriteLine(a["key3"][0][1]);
  }
}
```